# Scipy odeint breaks on discontinuous dynamics function e.g. xdot = -sgn(x)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical

I am trying to use `Python` and `scipy.integrate.odeint` to simulate the following dynamical system:

[image]

But this integration breaks numerically in `Python` resulting in the following and similar images (usually even worse than this):

[image]

Generated using the following in `iPython/Jupyter notebook`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

f = lambda x,t: -np.sign(x)
x0 = 3
ts = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
xs = odeint(f,x0,ts)
plt.plot(ts,xs)
plt.show()
```

Any advice how to better simulate such a system with discontinuous dynamics?

Edit #1:

Example result when ran with smaller timestep, `ts = np.linspace(0,10,1000000)`, in response to @Hun's answer.  This is also an incorrect result according to my expectations.

[image]

Comment: Just to add that I get different images upon repeating the execution of the code…

Comment: Also, running Python version:  2.7.11

Comment: I am using python 3.5.1, numpy 1.10.4, scipy 0.17.0.
It just worked fine when I ran your code exactly as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code exactly as shown and this is what I got.

[image]

Comment: Can you run it again several times please and report if you always get this image?

Comment: (This is what I expect it to look like)

Comment: ts = np.linspace(0,10,1000) # make this time step smaller. For example, make it 1e4.

Comment: Does not solve the problem.  I ran it on `https://try.jupyter.org/` with `Python 2` with the line `ts = np.linspace(0,10,1000000)` and got a related issue (see image added to my original post, because I can't include it within a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I also ran it exactly as shown and got:

[image]

Comment: This is another type of result that I get sometime…

Comment: Do you have any more information for that dynamical system, is it called anything that I may be able to look up?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that can work better is by implementing a custom `sgn()` function that has epsilon-tolerance around zero, instead of expecting precise equality with zero.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

sgn = lambda x,eps: (x<-eps)*(-1) + (x>=-eps and x<eps)*0 + (x>=eps)*1
f = lambda x,t: -sgn(x,1e-7)
x0 = 3
ts = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
xs = odeint(f,x0,ts)
plt.plot(ts,xs)
plt.show()
```

Note that an `eps` parameter of 1e-7 worked fine for me, but smaller than that seemed to crash.  It seems from `numpy.finfo` and demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141432/python-numpy-machine-epsilon/19141711#19141711) that the machine epsilon of `numpy.float32` is around 1e-7, while `float` is around 1e-16.