# How to avoid numeric error when normalizing min-max near zero?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision, numeric

I am using

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

v01 = preprocessing.minmax_scale(v01, feature_range=(rf_imp_vec_truncated.min(), rf_imp_vec_truncated.max()))
```

and it usually works, except for some times when I get errors like

```
    preprocessing.minmax_scale(v01, feature_range=(rf_imp_vec_truncated.min(), rf_imp_vec_truncated.max()))
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 510, in minmax_scale
    X = s.fit_transform(X)
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 571, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 339, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 365, in partial_fit
    " than maximum. Got %s." % str(feature_range))
ValueError: Minimum of desired feature range must be smaller than maximum. Got (-6.090366306515144e-15, -6.090366306515144e-15).
```

This looks like a numeric error, and I would like to see a flat line in this case.

How to get around this without too much code uglification?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're interpreting the meaning of `feature_range` correctly? The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale) mention, it is the range in which you want the output data, say [0, 1].

The docs also state that the `feature_index[0]` (i.e., the minimum) must be strictly less than `feature_index[1]` (i.e., the maximum). However, in your case both are equal (-6.09e-15 and -6.09e-15), hence the error.

Comment: Adding a guard `if rf_imp_vec_truncated.min() >= rf_imp_vec_truncated.max(): return` doesn't enter the `if` statement. This smells like numeric errors of subtracting two floats.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solutuion I could find for this was to add [epsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141432/python-numpy-machine-epsilon) to the max:

```
v01 = preprocessing.minmax_scale(v01, feature_range=(rf_imp_vec_truncated.min(), rf_imp_vec_truncated.max() + np.finfo(rf_imp_vec_truncated.dtype).eps))
```

Now they are no longer equal.